# Partial ordering rules of template parameter pack in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Here is an example from [temp.deduct.partial](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#8).

```
template<class... Args>           void f(Args... args);         // #1
template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args);  // #2
template<class T1, class T2>      void f(T1 a1, T2 a2);         // #3

f();                // calls #1
f(1, 2, 3);         // calls #2
f(1, 2);            // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more specialized
                    // than the variadic templates #1 and #2
```

Why `f(1, 2, 3)` calls `#2`?

It is easy to understand before [CWG1395](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1395). `#2` cannot be deduced from `#1` because `Args` is a parameter pack and `T1` is not, so `#2` is more specialized than `#1`.

But how to understand this example after CWG1395? It seems that `T1` can be deduced from `Args` now.

> Similarly, if `A` was transformed from a function parameter pack, it is compared with each remaining parameter type of the parameter template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CWG1395 does not appear to change anything related to the example you cited from the standard. Keep in mind that CWG1935 was issued to allow for e.g.

```cpp
    template<class T>
    void print(ostream &os, const T &t) {
        os << t;
    }

    template <class T, class... Args>
    void print(ostream &os, const T &t, const Args&... rest) {
        os << t << ", ";
        print(os, rest...);
    }

    int main() {
        print(cout, 42);
        print(cout, 42, 1.23);
    }
```

Prior to issue 1395, the argument pack expansion from the call `print(os, rest...)` could never be matched against the template parameter `T` of `void print(ostream &os, const T &t)`, as function parameter packs explicitly had to be matched against template parameter packs:

> If A was transformed from a function parameter pack and P is not a parameter pack, type deduction fails.

With the changes, the first `print` function now is allowed to be matched against the function parameter pack call and considered more specialized than the second overload by 13.10.3.5 [temp.deduct.partial] paragraph 10:

> If, after considering the above, function template F is at least as specialized as function template G and vice-versa, and if G has a trailing paramter pack for which F does not have a corresponding parameter, and if F does not have a trailing parameter pack, then F is more specialized than G.

Your example above however is not related to function parameter packs and thus not affected by the changes, so the rules of [[temp.deduct.type]/13.10.3.6 §10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#10) still apply.